# How to add mouse event in drawn canvas compoent

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, math, canvas

I want to draw 200 or more(highly fluid) object in canvas.
 and add mouse over, mouse click event each of them.

source code like this...
 (valiable k is increase)

'
         ....
         ....
         for( k = 0 ; k < 200; k++){ 
                      start = start[k];
 
                      end = end[k];
        x1 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*start)*0.9;
 
        y1 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*start)*0.9;
 
        x2 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*start)*0.95;
 
        y2 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*start)*0.95;
 
        x3 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*end)*0.95;
 
        y3 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*end)*0.95;
 
        x4 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*end)*0.9;
 
        y4 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*end)*0.9;

```
    Shape(ctx, x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,k);
```

}

```
    function Shape(ctx, x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4, k){
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";    
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0; 
        ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
        ctx.lineTo(x2,y2); 
        ctx.lineTo(x3,y3); 
        ctx.lineTo(x4,y4); 
        ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
        ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillText(k,(x2+x3)/2,(y2+y3)/2);    
    }

    ....
     ....
```

my hope is..
 if mouse over on shape, display valiable k 
 if mouse click on shape, go other url with valiable k parameter
 
 but, I did not want to use image.

 please help me. 

 thanks.

Comment: Questions have previews. Why did you click "Post Your Question" while it looks like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the shape's coordinates in an array, you can loop trough them and check for collision with the mouse's coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas are drawn like bitmap. All the changes are made to the pixels, and no trace of line or path would be kept. If you want to see whether a click is on or inside certain path, you need to implement you own hit test. If the shapes you draw can overlap each other, you will need to handle the order by yourself. It's doable, but you are on your own.

The other way out is to use SVG instead. Because SVG are objects, browser will keep track of them for you. You can just add `onclick` to an SVG element like you do to an HTML element.

The easiest solution would be just use library like d3: http://d3js.org/

Answer (score 0):

Since your shapes are irregular, it would be difficult to do hit-testing mathematically.

Fortunately, the context has the `isPointInPath` method that will test if the supplied mouseX / mouseY is inside the last defined path.

To hit-test your irregular shapes:

- Keep enough information to redefine each path in an object.
- Add each shape object to an array.
- In the mousemove event handler...
- Iterate through the array
- Redefine each shape (1 at a time). Note: redefining is drawing without stroke/fill.
- Use `context.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)` to hit-test if the mouse is inside the last defined shape.

Here is example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/o5xp21t2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";    
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0; 
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
    ctx.font="14px verdana";

    var centerX=150;
    var centerY=150;
    var radius=120;
    var arg=1;
    var start=0;
    var end=Math.PI/8;
    var shapes=[];

    for(var k=0;k<10;k++){
        start+=Math.PI/8;
        end+=Math.PI/8;
        x1 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*start)*0.9;
        y1 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*start)*0.9;
        x2 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*start)*0.95;
        y2 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*start)*0.95;
        x3 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*end)*0.95;
        y3 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*end)*0.95;
        x4 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*end)*0.9;
        y4 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*end)*0.9; 
        var s={x1:x1,y1:y1,x2:x2,y2:y2,x3:x3,y3:y3,x4:x4,y4:y4,k:k};
        shapes.push(s);
        Shape(s,k,true);
    }

    $results=$("#results");

    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      for(var k=0;k<shapes.length;k++){
          Shape(shapes[k],k,false);
          if(ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)){
              $results.text("Last mouseover: "+k);
          }
      }
    }

    function Shape(s, k, draw){
        ctx.fillStyle="red";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(s.x1,s.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(s.x2,s.y2); 
        ctx.lineTo(s.x3,s.y3); 
        ctx.lineTo(s.x4,s.y4); 
        ctx.lineTo(s.x1,s.y1);
        if(draw){
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fillStyle="blue";
            ctx.fillText(k,(s.x2+s.x3)/2,(s.y2+s.y3)/2);    
        }
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id=results>Hover mouse over shapes.</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```